# SSRS Date Picker Display Issue

Tags: reporting-services, datepicker, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

When click on SSRS report's date picker icon , it will no be displayed but stuck with “Loading” word  (I am using reporting service 2016)

(This happen in both latest version of Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome browser)

Image1

[image: 1]

Following is the error i can see in web browser's console tab

Image2

[image: 2]

Do anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Have you tried a different machine?

Comment: Yes, but it still happens the same

Comment: It may be an issue with the server that you're running the report manager on. Is it a new problem or has it never worked? If it's new, check the last installed updates on the server. If it's never worked then you may have a n older version of SSRS installed.